# Clarification of the exact function of NSNotificationCenter

Tags: cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm still picking up ObjC and I'm just trying to make sure I understand the concept of `NSNotification`s *fully*:

The `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` is a stationary object which is **not** the *sender* or the *receiver*. It merely *routes* an `NSNotification`, but in no way, shape, or form handles the event (by default).

Is that correct?

*Theory:*
Would that allow an `AppDelegate` to *push* a notification to the `defaultCenter` and have something further on in the responder chain / display list (e.g., `UITableViewCell`) pick up on the action?

Comment: +1 for @yuji's answer, just a couple of points on terminology. + defaultCenter is not a 'stationary object' (at least i don't know what a stationary object is). It's like a global pinboard (per app) that notices can be posted to. The Responder Chain is involved in handling UI Events/Actions. It has nothing todo with notifications. Also checkout NSNotificationQueue..

Comment: I think he means it's a singleton, which it is.

Comment: @RobKeniger - i know what he meant, but that doesn't make it good practice to make up your own names. And, no, it isn't :)

Comment: That's interesting, I've always assumed it was. It certainly acts as one. More info?

Comment: I think what @hooleyhoop is referring to is that you can make your own notification center with `alloc init`, although in the vast majority of use cases people just grab the shared instance with `defaultCenter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. `NSNotificationCenter` is just the clearinghouse for the notifications. It keeps track of all the objects observing each notification, so that when a notification is posted, it can be routed to all the right observers.

And yeah, no reason why your `AppDelegate` can't post a notification that gets picked up by things like a `UITableViewCell`. `NSNotifications` are great for situations where an object has to send data to other objects, or tell them that something happened, and you won't know what the recipients should be until runtime.